# Why Hibernate automatically perform these queries and give me this jaxon exception trying to return an object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jackson, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a Spring Boot application using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate mapping and I have the following Hibernate problem trying to implement an API intended to enable\disable an user on my application (basically it only update a **isActive** boolean field). I will try to describe what is my problem.

First of all this is my **User** entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "portal_user")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User implements Serializable {
     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5062673109048808267L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.firstName.Validation}")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;
    
    @Column(name = "surname")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.surname.Validation}")
    private String surname;
    
    @Column(name = "sex")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.sex.Validation}")
    private char sex;
    
    @Column(name = "birthdate")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.birthdate.Validation}")
    private Date birthdate;
    
    @Column(name = "tax_code")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.taxCode.Validation}")
    private String taxCode;
    
    @Column(name = "e_mail")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.email.Validation}")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name = "pswd")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.pswd.Validation}")
    private String pswd;
    
    @Column(name = "contact_number")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.contactNumber.Validation}")
    private String contactNumber;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
    
    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private boolean is_active;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "address")
    private Set<Address> addressesList = new HashSet<>();
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "portal_user_user_type", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "portal_user_id_fk") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_type_id_fk") }
    )
    Set<UserType> userTypes;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonProperty("subagent")
    private User parent;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "user-wallets")
    private Set<Wallet> wallets = new HashSet<>();


    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public User(String firstName, String middleName, String surname, char sex, Date birthdate, String taxCode,
            String email, String pswd, String contactNumber, Date createdAt, boolean is_active) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.taxCode = taxCode;
        this.email = email;
        this.pswd = pswd;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.is_active = is_active;
    }
    

}
```

Then this is my controller method implementing my API:

```
@ApiOperation(
          value = "Activate or deactivate an user", 
          notes = "activate value are true or false to activate or deactivate an user",
          produces = "application/json")
@PutMapping(value = "/{userId}", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<User> activateDeactivateUser(@PathVariable("userId") String userId,
                                                   @RequestBody Map<String, String> json) throws NotFoundException  {
    
    boolean activate = false;
    
    log.info(String.format("****** json BODY: %s *******", json));
    log.info(String.format("****** json active field value: %s *******", json.get("active")));
    
    activate = Boolean.parseBoolean(json.get("active"));
    
    if(activate)
        log.info(String.format("****** Activate the user having ID : %s *******", userId));
    else
        log.info(String.format("****** Deactivate the user having ID : %s *******", userId));

    User user = this.userService.activateDeactivateUser(Integer.parseInt(userId), activate).get();
    
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

It is pretty simple: it extract the JSON field value of the **activate** from the request body and use it to call a service method that activate or deactivate the user represented by the **userId** path variable.

Finnally this is is my **activateDeactivateUser()** service method:

```
@Override
public Optional<User> activateDeactivateUser(int userId, boolean isActive) throws NotFoundException {
    
    Optional<User> retrievedUser = this.userRepository.findById(userId);
    
    if(retrievedUser.isEmpty())
        throw new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID or email %s was not found", userId));
    
    
    return Optional.ofNullable(retrievedUser) 
            .map((user) -> { 
                log.info(String.format("****** USER E-MAIL *******", user.get().getEmail()));
                
                user.get().set_active(isActive);
                this.userRepository.save(user.get());
                
                return user;
                })
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID or email %s was not found", userId)));
}
```

It first retrieve the user that must be updated from the DB, then update it by the Spring Data JPA **save()** method call. Finally it return the **Optional** updated object to the controller API method that called this service method.

What is the problem?

I perform the call to my API passing a JSON like this into the request body:

```
{
    "active": "true"
}
```

it enter into the controller, then it call the previous service method. First of all it correctly retrieve the expecting object by this line:

```
Optional<User> retrievedUser = this.userRepository.findById(userId);
```

Then it enter into the **map()** operator, it change the status and correctly update the object on the DB calling the **save()** method (checking on the DB the column of this record is correctly updated). Then it return the **Optional** object to my controller method.

Last operations made by the controller method are:

1. Extract the **User** object from the **Optional** object (returned by the service method):

   User user = this.userService.activateDeactivateUser(Integer.parseInt(userId), activate).get();

it seems to works fine

2. and finnally return the **ResponseEntity**:

   return new ResponseEntity(user, HttpStatus.OK);

and here I have the problem: it seems that executing this operation Hibernate automatically performed some queries and then give me an excepetion, following the obtained stacktrace:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        usertypes0_.portal_user_id_fk as portal_u2_5_0_,
        usertypes0_.user_type_id_fk as user_typ3_5_0_,
        usertype1_.id as id1_6_1_,
        usertype1_.description as descript2_6_1_,
        usertype1_.type_name as type_nam3_6_1_ 
    from
        portal_user_user_type usertypes0_ 
    inner join
        user_type usertype1_ 
            on usertypes0_.user_type_id_fk=usertype1_.id 
    where
        usertypes0_.portal_user_id_fk=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        operations0_.fk_user_type_id as fk_user_1_7_0_,
        operations0_.fk_operation_id as fk_opera2_7_0_,
        operation1_.id as id1_3_1_,
        operation1_.description as descript2_3_1_,
        operation1_.name as name3_3_1_ 
    from
        user_type_operation operations0_ 
    inner join
        operation operation1_ 
            on operations0_.fk_operation_id=operation1_.id 
    where
        operations0_.fk_user_type_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        wallets0_.fk_user_id as fk_user_5_8_0_,
        wallets0_.id as id1_8_0_,
        wallets0_.id as id1_8_1_,
        wallets0_.address as address2_8_1_,
        wallets0_.fk_coin_id as fk_coin_4_8_1_,
        wallets0_.notes as notes3_8_1_,
        wallets0_.fk_user_id as fk_user_5_8_1_,
        wallets0_.type as type6_8_1_,
        coin1_.id as id1_2_2_,
        coin1_.code as code2_2_2_,
        coin1_.description as descript3_2_2_,
        coin1_.logo as logo4_2_2_,
        coin1_.name as name5_2_2_,
        wallettype2_.id as id1_9_3_,
        wallettype2_.name as name2_9_3_ 
    from
        wallet wallets0_ 
    left outer join
        coin coin1_ 
            on wallets0_.fk_coin_id=coin1_.id 
    left outer join
        wallet_type wallettype2_ 
            on wallets0_.type=wallettype2_.id 
    where
        wallets0_.fk_user_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_4_0_,
        user0_.birthdate as birthdat2_4_0_,
        user0_.contact_number as contact_3_4_0_,
        user0_.created_at as created_4_4_0_,
        user0_.e_mail as e_mail5_4_0_,
        user0_.first_name as first_na6_4_0_,
        user0_.is_active as is_activ7_4_0_,
        user0_.middle_name as middle_n8_4_0_,
        user0_.parent_id as parent_13_4_0_,
        user0_.pswd as pswd9_4_0_,
        user0_.sex as sex10_4_0_,
        user0_.surname as surname11_4_0_,
        user0_.tax_code as tax_cod12_4_0_,
        addressesl1_.fk_user_id as fk_user_7_1_1_,
        addressesl1_.id as id1_1_1_,
        addressesl1_.id as id1_1_2_,
        addressesl1_.country as country2_1_2_,
        addressesl1_.notes as notes3_1_2_,
        addressesl1_.province as province4_1_2_,
        addressesl1_.street as street5_1_2_,
        addressesl1_.fk_user_id as fk_user_7_1_2_,
        addressesl1_.zip_code as zip_code6_1_2_ 
    from
        portal_user user0_ 
    left outer join
        address addressesl1_ 
            on user0_.id=addressesl1_.fk_user_id 
    where
        user0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        usertypes0_.portal_user_id_fk as portal_u2_5_0_,
        usertypes0_.user_type_id_fk as user_typ3_5_0_,
        usertype1_.id as id1_6_1_,
        usertype1_.description as descript2_6_1_,
        usertype1_.type_name as type_nam3_6_1_ 
    from
        portal_user_user_type usertypes0_ 
    inner join
        user_type usertype1_ 
            on usertypes0_.user_type_id_fk=usertype1_.id 
    where
        usertypes0_.portal_user_id_fk=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        operations0_.fk_user_type_id as fk_user_1_7_0_,
        operations0_.fk_operation_id as fk_opera2_7_0_,
        operation1_.id as id1_3_1_,
        operation1_.description as descript2_3_1_,
        operation1_.name as name3_3_1_ 
    from
        user_type_operation operations0_ 
    inner join
        operation operation1_ 
            on operations0_.fk_operation_id=operation1_.id 
    where
        operations0_.fk_user_type_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        wallets0_.fk_user_id as fk_user_5_8_0_,
        wallets0_.id as id1_8_0_,
        wallets0_.id as id1_8_1_,
        wallets0_.address as address2_8_1_,
        wallets0_.fk_coin_id as fk_coin_4_8_1_,
        wallets0_.notes as notes3_8_1_,
        wallets0_.fk_user_id as fk_user_5_8_1_,
        wallets0_.type as type6_8_1_,
        coin1_.id as id1_2_2_,
        coin1_.code as code2_2_2_,
        coin1_.description as descript3_2_2_,
        coin1_.logo as logo4_2_2_,
        coin1_.name as name5_2_2_,
        wallettype2_.id as id1_9_3_,
        wallettype2_.name as name2_9_3_ 
    from
        wallet wallets0_ 
    left outer join
        coin coin1_ 
            on wallets0_.fk_coin_id=coin1_.id 
    left outer join
        wallet_type wallettype2_ 
            on wallets0_.type=wallettype2_.id 
    where
        wallets0_.fk_user_id=?
[2m2022-01-18 19:56:07.409[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m15285[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-2][0;39m [36ms.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
[2m2022-01-18 19:56:07.421[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m15285[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8019-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.easydefi.users.entity.User["subagent"]->com.easydefi.users.entity.User$HibernateProxy$5t5vQByS["hibernateLazyInitializer"])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.easydefi.users.entity.User["subagent"]->com.easydefi.users.entity.User$HibernateProxy$5t5vQByS["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1276) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1514) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1006) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:454) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at com.easydefi.users.security.TokenVerificationFilter.doFilterInternal(TokenVerificationFilter.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

What could be the problem? How can I try to solve it?

```
return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

Long story short : Because the `User` 's `parent` is configured as lazy loading , the `parent` instance inside the loaded `User` entity is actually a hibernate proxy but not the normal Java instance and hence Jackson does not know how to serialize it to JSON and throw this exception.

The proper fix for me to do create another DTO for the API JSON response and map the result entity to this DTO and return from the controller rather than directly expose the entities to the world especially for the case that the JSON response structure is not trivial or and its structure is quite different from the entities. Because it will just make your entities to couple with the API response which make you very difficult to evolve your application as whenever you change the entities , you have to worry about that your changes will not affect the existing API client.

But if you insist do not want to do it , you can try to unproxy the `parent` to an actual instance using `Hibernate.unproxy()` and configure the necessary Jackson annotations to serialize this unproxy `parent` . Something likes :

```java
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User parent;

    @JsonProperty("subagent")
    public User getUnproxyParent(){
       return Hibernate.unproxy(parent, User.class);
    }
   
}
```

*<sub>*P.S.* Just give you the idea.You may need to revise the corresponding Jackson annotation to make it work , and it is ugly IMO.</sub>*

Comment: Thank you for your clear explaination. So do you think that the best thing that I can do is to create something like a UserDTO class and properly map the entity instances on these DTO instances? tnx again

Comment: Yes. just my opinion although i know someone may disagree